# Euler characteristic of odd dimensional manifold - Hatcher

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, poincare-duality

I ran into some trouble while reading through Hatcher's proof of the following:

> **Corollary 3.37.** *A closed manifold of odd dimension has Euler characteristic zero.*

There is only one part of the proof that I don't understand. He writes

> "Each $\mathbb{Z}_m$ summand of $H_i(M;\mathbb{Z})$ with $m$ even gives $\mathbb{Z}_2$ summands of $H^i(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and $H^{i-1}(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, [...]."

I have been able to show that we indeed get $\mathbb{Z}_2$  summands in $H^i(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ (if helpful, I can edit this post to include this proof), but I fail to see that this is also the case in $H^{i-1}(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$. My best guess is that it follows from the UCT, but I haven't been able to show it.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Another approach to proving the question which I find a bit simpler is to pass to the orientable double cover if necessary first. In the orientable case, the answer follows from Poincare Duality, and in the unoriented case, use the fact that a 2-fold cover ha $\chi=0$ and the multiplicativity of euler characteristic on finite covers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your version of the book (or you read it wrong). It gives a copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in $H^{i+1}$, not $H^{i-1}$. In my version of the book it is right.

This is a consequence of the shift in the index of $\operatorname{Ext}$ in the UCT:
$$ H^n(C;\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(C),\mathbb{Z}_2)\oplus \operatorname{Ext}(H_{n-1}(C),\mathbb{Z}_2),$$
notice the indices.

Hence, $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$  and $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2/m\mathbb{Z}_2\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ if $m$ is even.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpful! It seems to be a mistake, it really says $H^{i-1}$ in my version of the book.